# Sending ZeroMQ data using TCP

Tags: http, tcp, server, zeromq

I am trying to make a simple server.

A language I am restricted to use is c++.

I am using `ZeroMQ`.

I have creatred a simple server and a client, as in documentation.

`ZeroMQ` uses **`TCP`** instead of `HTTP`.

I know that `HTTP`'s underlying layer is `TCP`, so I want to know will it have any performance issues by using `TCP` instead of `HTTP`.

And for `HTTP` I can use **`curl`** to test the application.

What should I use for `TCP` ( `curl` command to send request to a socket with a string parameter ).

---

***Server:***

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void)
{                                                  // Socket to talk to clients
   void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
   void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
   int rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555");
   assert (rc == 0);

   while (1)
   {
      char buffer [10];
      zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 10, 0);
      printf ("Received Hello\n");

                                                   // trying to send json object
      zmq_send (responder, "World", 5, 0);
   // zmq_send (responder, "World", 5, 0);
      sleep (1);                                   // Do some 'work'
   }
   return 0;
}
```

***client:***

```
// Hello World client
// Connects REQ socket to tcp://localhost:5555
// Sends "Hello" to server, expects "World" back

#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main (void)
{
   void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
                                                   // Socket to talk to server
   printf ("Connecting to hello world server...\n");
   void *requester = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
   zmq_connect (requester, "tcp://localhost:5555");
   int request_nbr;
   for (request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++)
   {   
       zmq_msg_t request;
       zmq_msg_init_size (&request, 5);
       memcpy (zmq_msg_data (&request), "Hello", 5);
       printf ("Sending Hello %d...\n", request_nbr);
       zmq_msg_send (&request, requester, 0);
       zmq_msg_close (&request);
       zmq_msg_t reply;

       zmq_msg_init (&reply);
       zmq_msg_recv (&reply, requester, 0);
       printf ("Received World %d\n", request_nbr);
       zmq_msg_close (&reply);
   }
   zmq_close (requester);
   zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: From RFC 2616:
HTTP communication usually takes place over TCP/IP connections. The default port is TCP 80, but other ports can be used. This does not preclude HTTP from being implemented on top of any other protocol on the Internet, or on other networks. HTTP only presumes a reliable transport; any protocol that provides such guarantees can be used; the mapping of the HTTP/1.1 request and response structures onto the transport data units of the protocol in question is outside the scope of this specification.

Comment: @Yogesh I understand that http is built over  tcp. also i understand the request response structure of http. my question is how to query using curl to a socket. and using tcp will it create any performance overhead?

Comment: Using a lower layer can only improve performance, not make it worse.

Comment: While I tend to agree, it's not a lower layer but a paralle one, because it's ZeroMQ on top of TCP, just as it's HTTP on top of TCP. Concerning the testing, use a ZMQ lib implemented in a simple scripting language, like e.g. Python. It provides an interactive shell to quickly send a few messages.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** will it have any performance issues by using `TCP` instead of `HTTP`?
**A1:** yes, it will. Both performance and latency will benefit from avoiding `HTTP`-rich-re-wrapping of data

**Q2:** What should I use for `TCP` to send a request to a socket with a string parameter?
**A2:** No command ( `curl` command ) will help you. **`ZeroMQ`** uses certain line-code ( assume it as a trivial protocol between communicationg peers ), so a standalone command-line tool will not be able to match the line-code requirement off-the-shelf. **Solution?** Create a simple c-programme, that will consume a cmd-line arguments ( the string, as an example ) and assemble a ZeroMQ-layer compatible data-framing so as to communicate with the remote peer. Also you shall notice, that for `ZeroMQ` **`REQ/REP`** Formal Communication Pattern to work, this proxy-tool will have to become the sole respective **`REQ`**, resp. **`REP`** entity in the step-forward-locking diadic-communication relation, thus also providing an awaited response, the **`REQ`**-side is expecting to receive after the **`REP`**-side has received a message.